# How do I download Chromium dev build for OSX?

Tags: google-chrome

I'd like to try [process monitor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/process-monitor/dmpncdjcpgnbcgfkboljpaagkkkcbbbk?hl=en-GB), and it requires the dev build, pointing you to [this page](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel#TOC-Mac). The same page also appears if I search for it on google.

However, that page includes a link for the "OSX dev build" which actually brings you to the normal Chrome download page, from which you just download the normal version. Same fate if you try the Windows link, just to be sure.

Brew lists a chromium cask, but since it's unspecified, I assume it's the normal build, not the dev one.

`lohoris@Pirenne-054:~$ brew search chromium
Caskroom/cask/chromium             Caskroom/cask/freesmug-chromium
lohoris@Pirenne-054:~$ brew cask info chromium
chromium: latest
Chromium
http://www.chromium.org/Home
Not installed
https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/chromium.rb
==> Contents
  chrome-mac/Chromium.app (app)`

Do I have to build it from the sources? I can if I have to, but it would make the result a bit useless: a self-updating app is much better, if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chrome Dev Build is `Chrome Canary`. You can get Canary by clicking on this link

https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html?platform=mac

Comment: Technically, [Chrome/Chromium Dev build is different than Chrome/Chromium Canary](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel). Dev is built once or twice a week. Canary is built nightly. So there will be a slight version difference. The biggest difference is that you can install Canary side by side with Stable/Beta/Dev.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to getting updated: first one is an app called [chromatic](https://mrgeckosmedia.com/applications/info/chromatic). The second one is using a [shell script](https://github.com/mozamimy/chromium-updater).

Both alternatives will get the most recent dev build.

[Source](http://chromium.woolyss.com/#updater)

Comment: Can you expand your answer a bit? Just pointing to a product doesn't really explain how to accomplish the solution, and it's often viewed as spam. It's better to include some instructions on how to use the product to solve the problem, or at least describe what makes the product a good solution. Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my answer but it isn't spam considering that I'm offering two different solutions to achieve what the user need.

Comment: leozera, by "spam", I was referring here to how readers view software recommendations that are just a link, not the site's definition or your motives.  The site is a knowledge base, so the Q&A format is intended to create actionable solutions.  In this case, the accepted answer isn't an exemplary model for what's valued on the site, so you aren't likely to be held to a higher standard.  Typically, though, just links to tools that can be used for a solution would go in a comment.  An answer should provide value beyond the link.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `brew cask install chromium` will install the very Latest version of Chromium (currently 2 major versions ahead of Stable), if that's what you need.

If you look in the brew cask source, you will see that it is downloading the package from https://download-chromium.appspot.com, which only provides the Latest version right off the code repository. That means it's newer than Dev and even Canary.

https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/chromium.rb